# Accessing ArrayList returned as type Collection<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am implementing an interface which contains an ArrayList of objects Station. It uses the following code to return the ArrayList as type Collection.

```
public class NetworkImpl implements Network {

    private Collection<Station> stationList = new ArrayList<Station>();

    public Collection<Station> getStations() {
        return stationList;
    }
}
```

After I have populated the stationList ArrayList, I am unable to access individual stations directly, how would I go about doing this? I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Network newNetwork = new NetworkImpl(); // This is implemented and populated elsewhere
    newNetwork.getStations().get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you require random access to elements of the Collection, `getStations()` should return a `List<Station>` and not a `Collection<Station>`.

Of course you can cast the returned `Collection` to a `List` or `ArrayList` (after using `instanceof` to verify its type), but if the method returns a `Collection`, there's no guarantee that its implementation wouldn't change one day to return a `Set`, which would break your code that relies on random access.

Another option is to construct an `ArrayList` based on the returned `Collection` - `new ArrayList<Station>(newNetwork.getStations())`, which would guarantee that you end up with an `ArrayList`, regardless of what type of `Collection` is returned by the method.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a school assignment, I am unable to change the class they have given us to implement.

Comment: @user3371750 You don't have to change the interface code. Search for "covariant return type".

Comment: @Eng.Fouad See my answer, is that what you meant?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster No. Just change the type of `stationList` and `getStations()` inside `NetworkImpl`, from `Collection<Station>` to `List<Station>`.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster the OP said **"I am implementing an interface"**.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably [iterate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator()) over the Collection using an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Or, as suggested by @Eng.Fouad, since Java 5 you can specify a narrower return type in your implementation:

```
public class NetworkImpl implements Network {

   private List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<Station>();

    // covariant return type: narrower than Collection<List>     
    public List<Station> getStations() {
        return stations ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection interface has no get(index) method.Please find the api here 
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html][1]

instead, use iterator() method on getStations();

```
Iterator itr = newNetwork.getStations().iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()) {
itr.next(); // object you needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface.

Two methods are clearly for accessing the items in the collection. There's [iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) which will allow you to step through all of the elements in the collection in some sequence and there's [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29) which would allow you to access the elements by an index.

Answer (score -2):

You can cast Collection to List in this case

```
((List<Station>)newNetwork.getStations()).get(0);
```

Comment: This is a poor design, it couples the code to the NetworkImpl implementation.